# Lodash library is not removing from node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, lodash

I was using lodash methods in my Vuejs project but due to bundle size issues, I replaced all lodash methods with core js methods.

Now, I want to remove lodash library from my project. I tried all npm uninstall commands. For instance-

```
npm uninstall lodash
npm uninstall lodash --save
npm uninstall lodash --save-dev
npm uninstall -g lodash --save
```

but lodash is still in package-lock.json and in yarn. lock.

Additionally, when I build my project and checked the bundle size (using [webpack bundler analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer)), it is also displaying lodash in the bundle with 529kb size occupied space.

[image]

Lodash library is taking a huge amount of space in the bundle. Can anyone suggest how to
remove lodash from a Vuejs project.

Comment: delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file and then npm install

Comment: You can try npm cache clean and npm cache verify if it not works

Comment: You also need to check if some other library depends on lodash. You may not be using it directly, but some if some npm library has dependency on lodash, it'll be part of your bundle.

Comment: I removed package-lock.json, yarn.lock and node_modules and run yarn install (As I am using yarn in my project) but lodash get installed somehow and it is in yarn.lock file. @HDM91

Comment: How can I verify if any other library has a dependency on lodash? Is there any tool or do I need to research manually? @KanishkAnand

Comment: @NehaSoni you should check yarn.lock and check wherever "lodash" is mentioned. That should give you idea that which packages depend on lodash

Comment: Of course, it will be in lock file, it's a popular package and obviously is used by some dev deps at least. It's unknown why it's included into a bundle, this is a totally different question and needs to be investigated for your project. It's used in either your own code or client-side deps

Comment: @n For the future use cases, remember that lodash has a feature that let you import single functions separately in your project to reduce a lot the size of the dependency.

Comment: Yes, here are some libraries in dev dependencies that are using lodash as a dependency.

Comment: Don't worry because the dev dependency has no effect on your final output and is only used in the develop section and you can't delete this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, neither of those `npm uninstall` commands worked for me either.

This worked for me:

1. Open `package.json`.
2. Find the line which has `lodash` with its version and remove it.
3. Perform `npm install` inside your client project's folder.
4. Restart the app.

Note for Angular: As of today `Karma` uses lodash. Disregard it if you see some lodash in `package.lock.json`. Your `package.json` matters in this case.